# How do I reorder characters in a String without the use of Hashmaps?

Tags: java, string, parsing, character

My code below is giving the following error and I can't figure out why. I am trying to reorder the entered word ("**Polish**" for example) in the order of:

(First letter, last letter, second letter, second last letter, third letter... so on) so the output should be "**Phosli**".

[image: Screenshot]

Updated code

```
public static String encodeTheWord(String word1)
{
    int b = 0;
    int e = word1.length()-1;
    String word2 = "";   
    for (int i=0; i<e; i++)
    {
        word2 = word2 + word1.charAt(b) + word1.charAt(e);
        b+=1;
        e-=1;
    }

    System.out.println(word2);

    return (word2);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; just post the text itself.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a word with an even amount of characters (Polish), the order of the characters becomes `051423`, so the maximum value of `b` is `2` and the minimum value is `e` is from `5` to `3`. Thus, your loop should decrement `e` and increment `b` twice (so you run the loop for `word1.length() / 2` times). Also,

`int e = word1.length();`

Would need to be:

`int e = word1.length() - 1;`

For words of an uneven length (`word1.length() % 2 > 0`) you need an extra check or you will repeat the middle character.

Comment: you're right, the first solution worked only on "polish" and other even words. but "water" came out as wrae. ill try your solution now and see how it turns out

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't get your solution to work. could you elaborate? ill post my updated code (which only works with uneven words) in the question!

Comment: Your loop termination condition `i < e` may work by accident but it is bad practice to use a variable that is changed within the loop there. Instead, you probably want `word1.length() / 2`. Note that this uses integer division, so if the word length is 7 then this will be `i < 3`, and it will run for `i = 0, 1, 2`. In this (uneven) case you miss the middle letter, so after the loop add an additional `if`-statement: `if (word1.length() % 2 > 0) word2 = word2 + word1.charAt(b);`.

Answer (score 1):

your for loop is wrong, you can get a char at index **0**, until the **word1.length()-1**...

must be

```
for (int i=0; i<word1.length()-1; i++)
```

the same applies for this...

```
word1.charAt(e);
```

because you defined **e** as **word1.length()**

Comment: the same applies for this :  word1.charAt(e);, e must be word1.length()-1